# Invoke concurrent functions sequentially

Tags: ios, swift, swift-concurrency

#### Overview

- I have a function `f1` which is non-async function.
- `f1` gets called multiple times and I have no control over the calling of `f1`
- When f1 gets called I would like to invoke an async function `f2`

#### Aim:

- I would like `f2` to complete before the next `f2` executes

#### Question:

- How can I ensure `f2` executes in sequence? (sample code below)

```
//I have no control over f1
//f1 can get called multiple times in quick succession.
func f1() {
    Task {
        try await f2() // Next time f1 gets called it should wait for the previous f2 to complete then should execute f2
    }
}

func f2() async throws {}
```

Comment: Put `f2` into an actor. What you're describing is exactly what an actor is for.

Comment: Actors are suitable if data race is a primary concern. If the order of execution is more of a concern, then Combine or OperationQueue would be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt and Kiril and, very valuable points, exactly what I was looking for and was very helpful in understanding what tool to use for what purpose